# Does Magento 2 actually support MD5? It doesn't seem to

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I have migrated customers from M1 to M2, everything came across fine however, the passwords have the following appended to the end:

```
:0
```

This is the code signifying that the hash is in MD5 format which is expected as this is standard for M1:

```
/**
 * Key of md5 algorithm
 */
const HASH_VERSION_MD5 = 0;

/**
 * Key of sha256 algorithm
 */
const HASH_VERSION_SHA256 = 1;
```

However, no passwords work. Oddly when I remove the code on the end of the password it does work.

I could just remove it from all passwords but it feels hacky and I'm not sure why it wouldn't just work based on the code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this URL. It will help you to clear your doubts
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/encryption-key.html

Comment: Thanks. I mean I know what an encryption key is though, are you suggesting that this is the issue? I would have thought if the encryption key didn't match the M1 version then it wouldn't be able to decrypt it without the :0 on the end? I have double checked this anyway and they are identical on M1 and M2. I'm also aware that SHA-256 is a stronger more modern method but as a step 1 I would atleast like to get passwords working before rehashing them all.... so my issue remains